# Why the image does not fade in on top of existing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=250px bgcolor=#FF0000>
    <tr>
        <td align=right><span id=spnMain></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
#spnMain {
    background: url("theImages/searchButton.png") no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 28px;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#spnMain span {
    background: url("theImages/searchButton.png");
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    background-position: 0px -56px;
}
```

**JS CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("#spnMain").wrapInner("<span></span>");
     $("#spnMain span").css({
         "opacity": 0
     });

     $("#spnMain").hover(function () {
         $(this).children("span").animate({
             "opacity": 1
         }, 400);

     }, function () {

         $(this).children("span").animate({
             "opacity": 0
         }, 400);

     });
 });
```

Produces the following (the top is onload and the bottom when mouse is hovered:

[image]

How can I make the green button fade in on top of the purple button so it hides it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you ask for a javascript solution but you can do the same thing with css only (if you want to)

Way 1, sprites, no animation though: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/WBjS5/

Way 2, two images, css transition (a bit hacky):  http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/WBjS5/6/

```
#spnMain
{
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    background-image: url(**url to green button image**);
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    position: relative;
}

#spnMain:after
{
   position: absolute;
   width: inherit;
   height: inherit;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   content:"";
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   background-image: url(**url to red button image**);
}

#spnMain:hover:after
{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Update** the visibility property helps for IE8 support- no transition will occur, but the image will be swapped on mouse over. What should be good enough of a fallback for old "browsers".

Comment: The transition may Not work. But the fallback should be a simple Image swap. Is the animation that Important to you? If the swap did not work before See the updated answer the visibility Attribute could help

Comment: The above code is for Way 1 or Way 2? I think just a image swap is fine but that's not working either :/

Comment: I have added The property visibility.

Comment: Did that work for ie 8? If not i will update my answer tomorrow

Comment: I will do a pastebin of what I have and it's not displaying anything. It's Friday so I will be updating you on Monday if you can please take a look

Comment: Perfect. Will do. Should be a tiny issue

Comment: Here is the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/j5cGbNxE It's not displaying anything in the table cell :/

Comment: @SiKni8 i've taken your pastebin and just changed the image path + some table styles for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/Le8kA/1/ this works like expected in IE8- simple image swap. Please check the image urls and or clean your browser chache. Make also sure there is no bad JS applied to the element as well (like the JS of your example in the question) I've also updated the fiddle in my answer with tested IE8 fallback. Please text me if your problems persists.

Comment: I just tested in IE8 and FF and it's working great! I will do a few more test in a few other browsers and report back to you. I already accepted your answer because it was working but it wasn't a clean hack. Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 3):

```
#spnMain {
    position: relative;
    /* ... same as before ... */
}
#spnMain span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* ... same as before */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

And your answer is:

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/LNQq3/4/

**CSS Code:**

```
#spnMain {
    background: url("http://s18.postimg.org/balg05zj9/gogo.gif?noCache=1393616120") no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -5px;
    width: 28px;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#spnMain:hover {
    background-position: -37px -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an absolute positioned element within a relative positioned element (http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)?

I have put together a quick jsfiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/9xENQ/

I just grabbed a quick GO/STOP image sprite and didn't take the time to really look into the necessary background-position to make it line up perfectly. Just wanted to convey the concept.

The HTML:

```
<div class="button-container">
    Hi here is a bunch of text with a padding right to keep it from bleeding into the image. 
    <span id="spnMain"></span>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.button-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 160px;
    width: 158px;
    height: 163px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#spnMain {
    background: url("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ2m3WvngUNXOeQ4oItfopBO5VSA3OP7hhaHsjMrwHLlzYR4KeZPA") no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 158px;
    display: block;
    height: 163px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -158px;
}
#spnMain span {
    background: url("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ2m3WvngUNXOeQ4oItfopBO5VSA3OP7hhaHsjMrwHLlzYR4KeZPA");
    display: block;
    width: 158px;
    height: 163px;
    background-position: -158px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -158px;
}
```

Your JavaScript (as is):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#spnMain").wrapInner("<span></span>");
    $("#spnMain span").css({"opacity" : 0});



    $("#spnMain").hover(function(){

        $(this).children("span").animate({"opacity" : 1}, 400);

    }, function(){

        $(this).children("span").animate({"opacity" : 0}, 400);

    });


});
```

Comment: I did it bit differently and all browser works (yes even IE 8) but when it comes to IE 10 the hover image is a little different.